# What grammatical error is there in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

What grammatical error is in the following sentence:

> Five thousand years ago, the ancient inhabitants of Orkney- a fertile, green archipelago of the northern tip of modern Scotland

In the solution it says:

> The proposition of before northern tip has been used incorrectly.

Can anyone explain it to me why it is wrong and why 'off' should be used before northern tip?

Comment: Please, could you use a more explicative title?

Answer (score 1):

- A green archipelago OF the northern tip of modern Scotland - doesn't really mean anything. It is not idiomatic. Or it could mean it is attached to the mainland. Which obviously - it isn't as it's... an island!
- A green Archipelago OFF the northern tip of  modern Scotland - correctly refers to the island being related to the northern tip of Scotland but some distance away.

Your 'solution' is not grammatical, by the way - maybe that's a typo or three - if it read like this, it might make more sense:

- "the preposition 'of', before 'northern tip' - has been used incorrectly." (I think it's preposition here, not proposition!)

...Meaning - you need OFF with two f's - not OF, as the meaning is quite different.

Background:

When an island is 'off' something - it means 'somehow related - but some distance away' from it.

Other things can also be referred to as being 'off' something, for example:

- the Globe Theatre lies off the main street
- The market is off the main playing field
- the living room lies off the dining room.

https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=meaning+is+off&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-sg&client=safari